# Pydantic: change default mapping

Tags: python, orm, fastapi, pydantic

With this ORM:

```py
class Building(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    street = Column(String)
    city = Column(String)
    post_code = Column(String)
```

this code works:

```py
class BuildingOutSchema(base):
    id: int
    name: str
    street: str
    city: str
    post_code: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

 # Select company with id=1
 company = db.query(company).get(1)
 return CompanyOutSchema.from_orm(company)
```

How can I tell to the Pydantic, to construct the model like this (make this piece of code work)?

```py
class AddressSchema(BaseModel):
    street: str
    city: str
    post_code: str

class BuildingOutSchema(base):
    id: int
    name: str
    address: AddressSchema

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

 # Select company with id=1
 company = db.query(company).get(1)
 return CompanyOutSchema.from_orm(company)
```

Is it possible to rewrite from_orm somehow? Or can I specify it somehow in Pydantic's `Field` type? Or is there any simpler solution?

I don't want to map it by the hand, because I'll use this `BuildingOutSchema` as a list in the another model, so I would have to map it in cycle.

Comment: Have you heard of a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Your code is completely opaque like this and it has a bunch of unnecessary noise likely unrelated to the issue. I suspect that you can construct a much shorter MRE to showcase your problem without any need for database queries, if you think about it for just a bit longer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pydantic: change model structure mapping in nested model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74532368/pydantic-change-model-structure-mapping-in-nested-model)